# Calculate marginal pdf of $Y$ when marginal pdf of $X$ and conditional distribution of $Y$ is given

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution

The Question

> [image]

So I have tried the formula
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\cdot f_{X}(x)$ but I am not able to figure out the bounds and I am not sure what to do after the bounds are found

Please do let me know if you guys have any idea on how to solve this question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264) for typesetting math here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X}(y|x)=2x^2\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(x)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1/x)}(y)$$

now to calculate $f_Y(y)$ you have to integrate in X, that is

$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^1 2x^2dx=2/3$$

when $y \in[0;1]$

and

$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^{1/y} 2x^2 dx=\frac{2}{3y^3}$$

when $y>1$

To understand integral bounds it is useful to do a drawing of the integration area, first

Comment: Thanks for the idea on drawing the graph, I get it now!

Comment: Just a small doubt, could you explain the first expression, I am not able to understand the notation and the range for the right hand side of the expression

Comment: @RevanthKumarPerla : $x \in [0;1]$ and $y \in [0;1/x]$. Zero elsewhere