# How to get the marginal distribution by splitting the integral of one of two variables

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution

I am trying to follow [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267567/calculate-marginal-pdf-of-y-when-marginal-pdf-of-x-and-conditional-distribut/4267575#4267575). Sorry to ask to read another post, but I don't understand why the integration of X is not just between the limits [0,1], where X has support. Instead there is a second integral between 0 and 1/y. This is confusing and the recommendation of drawing the integration area is not helping. I get it that 1/y is meant to find the inverse of U[0,1/x], but in this case, why integrate [0,1] separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting should help see why calculating the marginal from the bivariate needs to be broken down into two different intervals:

[image]